Hearing about unethical research practices from the academic world hits me really hard. How can I learn to deal with this?
When I was a naive teenager (oh so long ago), I used to think that scientific research is that one human endeavor where there is no room for questionable practices because any such practices will be counter-productive to our very mission. As researchers, we search for truth, so anything that does not serve this search has no place in our academic realm. Lured by the vision of being part of something so valuable and collaborative, I became an academic. The longer I'm an academic, it hits me really hard when I hear about...

fraudulent researchers, some coming from prestigious institutions, some even still being kept by their institutions,
wasted resources and damage to the reputation of conducting research in general due to fabricated research results,
predatory journal practices that will publish just about anything,
the fight for citations that fuels unethical citation practices,
publishing AI-generated research & texts,
unethical authorship practices,
the rushed and poor-quality works being produced due to academics being overworked, spread too thin, and stressed by not meeting arbitrary metrics

...the list goes on.
How do you, academics, deal with frustration, loss of motivation, and loss of belief in the value of your occupation when you hear about those stories worldwide? The only reason why I ask this question is that I want to stay in academia. In the end, this occupation still fits my core values, and I personally enjoy all the good and collaborative sides of it. If I could learn to manage my frustration, loss of motivation, I could better focus on my little slice and doing good work for as long as I can.

You see that your own processes and dealings are ethical and you teach students to be ethical.

You will find even more of such staff outside of the academia.

You keep your house clean. Find friends who keep their house clean. Be an example, maybe also your students (or some of them) will keep their house clean. The biggest triumph if you set an example to someone who is on the fence who then, at some point, decides to keep their house clean when they were tempted to drop the trash on the floor. It's not an achievement if a clean-freak does so, but if only one or two of potential litterbugs decide, by observing you, that one more time to drop the trash into the can instead of on the floor, you have achieved success.

How would a scientist—ideally—deal with observations that don’t match his or her hypotheses or preconceptions? A growth opportunity!

@Aruralreader, ha, that's a nice perspective! :)

Could someone please explain why my question strongly depends on individual factors? Is it that the strategies to deal with this issue will be very personal?

@MoisheKohan: [citation required]

@postdoc: note that only one closure reason is given, even if different close-voters gave different reasons for their particular vote to close. I personally would have voted to close as "opinion-based", and I imagine that some of the actual close-voters also gave this reason. After all, you are asking for our particular and personal strategies for dealing with this, so there probably will not be one correct answer, nor one that is commonly accepted by the community.

FWIW, my personal impression is that the amount of sheer crap published outweighs actual falsifications by orders of magnitude, though this is probably field-dependent. Yes, each specific instance of fraud is more damaging than each instance of crap. But on the aggregate, I wonder whether the bona fide crap is not the bigger problem. As an AE and reviewer, I feel like the boy with a finger in the dike... but on the other side of the dike, there is not just water, but a sea of... you get the idea.
